# what are the differences between react-native run-android and expo start?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

on expo start react state updating properly but react-native android doesn't.

what difference between those commands and what I can I do avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using expo , then you should start your local development server by `expo start` command as according to the docs, [expo-docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/workflow/expo-cli/) for a managed workflow ,i.e if you are using expo then you should use it.

Suppose you have created a bare react-native project , i.e by using react-native cli command i.e `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` then . you should use `react-native run-android` as that uses react-native cli to start the local development server.

Hope it helps .feel free for doubts

Comment: so after eject project I should use expo start and must use expos build:android command?

Comment: no ,after ejecting to bare react-native project you need react-native run-android and for apk generateion , you need to go to android folder and type ,

./gradlew assembleDebug for debug apk